# Why isn't my thread autobumper working?

Tags: javascript

What it does is wait until the page is loaded, locate the quick reply button, click it, locate the textarea, change its value to "bump", click the quick reply button
btw the problem is NOT in the getElementsByAttribute function, i copied it from another script of mine in which it worked

```
window.onload=function(){

var t1=setTimeout(function(){getElementsByAttribute("src", "http://assets.bodybuilding.com/forum/bodybuilding/buttons/reply.gif")[0].click();},3000);

var t2=setTimeout(function(){getElementsByAttribute("class", "cke_source cke_enable_context_menu")[0].value = "bump";},3000);

var t3=setTimeout(function(){getElementsByAttribute("value", "Post Quick Reply")[0].click();},3000);


}



document.getElementsByAttribute = function( attrib, value, context_node, tag ) {
    var nodes = [];
    if ( context_node == null )
        context_node = this;
    if ( tag == null ) 
        tag = '*';
    var elems = context_node.getElementsByTagName(tag);

    for ( var i = 0; i < elems.length; i += 1 ) {
        if ( value ) {
            if ( elems[i].hasAttribute(attrib) && elems[i].getAttribute(attrib) == value )
                nodes.push(elems[i]);
        } else {
            if ( elems[i].hasAttribute(attrib) )
                nodes.push(elems[i]);
        }
    }
    return nodes;
}
```

Comment: How should we know why it's not working?  You haven't told us which site you're using it on, what you expected it to do, and what it's doing instead.  This isn't a "debug my code for me" kind of site -- we expect you to demonstrate what doesn't work, and show us how you arrived at that conclusion.

Comment: Just a guess as you don't really ask a question here, but all your setTimeouts have same timeout value so they all fire at same time. Maybe you want them staggered?????

Comment: Alright, im using bodybuilding.com (should work in any thread), what i expect it to do is add a comment that says "BUMP". its not doing anything - the page loads and nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

They have the same timeout values, so they will fire in the order they are listed in.. you're trying to click reply, before you click quick reply.. swap the order around, and it will likely work.